# Use SimpleXML to grab nested code

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php simplexml issue in reading an attribute that has a ‘column - : ’ in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912256/php-simplexml-issue-in-reading-an-attribute-that-has-a-column-in-its-name)

I'm in the process of learning PHP, so I'm making a weather app to display an image based on the weather. I'm using the Yahoo Weather API.

My problem is that I'm looking for a way to grab [the code of the weather, located next to yweather:condition](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12793465&u=f) . I found [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) but can't figure out how to grab something that's located in something like the way Yahoo does its xml in the form of

```
<yweather:condition text="Fair" code="34" temp="37"
```

So my question is how can I grab the **code="34"** portion of the Yahoo weather and display it as a variable like `$weathercode = 34;`?

Thanks for any and all help, and I'm here to give more details if you need them!

Also, I'm not sure if the title of this post is correct, so sorry if it's not!

Comment: searching for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yweather+simplexml yields plenty of results. Please use the search before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SimpleXMLElement::attributes call in a similar way to below.

```
$string = {Yahoo Weather Feed}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$weathercode = $xml->channel->item->children('yweather', true)->condition[0]->attributes()->code;
```

You may need to tinker to get it right, but this is just a guide.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this only get `code="34"` once? Because the `code="34"` changes with the weather, so sometimes it might be `code="50"` or `code="30"`

Comment: I updated my answer with something that actually works.

Comment: You are an awesome StackOverflow-er thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12793465&u=f');
var_dump($xml);
```

This will load the URL and dump the SimpleXML object.

[More on simplexml_load_file here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: Please don't use `var_dump()` with SimpleXML; it will lead you astray. Try one of these instead: https://github.com/imsop/simplexml_debug